# Finding average in a file

Tags: python, average, mean

One of the things I'm supposed to do is find the average inflation from data in a file I was given. It gives the `year`, `interest`, and `inflation`, with all the numbers below it. Looks something like this.

```
year interest inflation
1900  4.61    8.1
```

This goes on quite a bit further, all the way to 2008. I've made some progress with some help, courtesy of germancoder. I'm still stuck though.

Here's what the code looks like so far.

```
def myTest(file):
     with open ('filename', 'r') as f:
          inflation = []
          header = 1
          for line in f:
               if header !=1:
                    infl = line.split(",")[2]
                    inflation.append(float(infl))
                    header += 1

           avgInflation = sum(inflation)/len(inflation)

     return avgInflation
```

The problem , I think, was that the year interest inflation at the top was causing problems. So with help I added stuff to the code, but I'm still getting an error. It says division by zero error, line 11. Any thoughts on what I should do now?

The actual file name is Inflation.csv. I made a simple program myself which prints it in the interpreter, which shows it separated by commas, hence why  I did (",")

Comment: If len(inflation) is zero, this means you never append anything to your inflation list. And you never add anything to your list because you've set header to 1, and only carry out actions when header is not 1.

Comment: You've set header = 1. So, if block never gets executed. Inflation array is of size 0, division by zero error is inevitable.

Comment: You are passing in `file` but never using it.  (Also, a bad idea to use a variable with the same name as a builtin.)

Comment: Just move  `header += 1` in line with the `if header !=1` or just call `next(f)` and forget it. Also if you have csv you might be better using the csv lib to read the file. Although you seem to have spaces in what you have shown so not sure why you are splitting on commas then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition for appending to the header will never be met as `header += 1` is under the condition `header != 1` and `header`'s initial value is `1`. Therefore you are looping over the array and doing nothing. At the end of your method where you calculate the average, your `inflation` list is still empty so `len(inflation)` resolves to `0`.

Also you are reading the lines in the file incorrectly. I think you are wanting to read them as lines using `f.readlines()`?

```
def myTest(file):
     with open ('filename', 'r') as f:
          lines = f.readlines() <--- 2 
          inflation = []
          header = 1
          for line in lines:
               if header !=1:
                    infl = line.split(",")[2]
                    inflation.append(float(infl))
               header += 1 <--- 1 

           avgInflation = sum(inflation)/len(inflation)

     return avgInflation
```

Comment: They are reading the file correctly. Calling readlines would actually be a worse approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are initalizing `header = 1`, and you initialize the value of `infl` and `inflation` after checking if `header` is not one, hence, `avgInflation = sum(inflation)/len(inflation)` is effectively becoming:

`avgInflation = sum(0/len(0))`

Make sure to check that inflation has a value before using it in a division. Perhaps you meant to initialize `header = 0`

Comment: At the top, if I do header = 0 than it just tells me that it can't convert the string to a float :(

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the problem. The declaration and assignation `header = 0` doesn't involve a string at all.

Comment: Sorry yall, like I said, I'm very new to programming. Appreciate all the help! Could someone explain what += does?

Comment: It is exactly the same as doing `header = header + 1`

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def myTest(file):
    with open ('filename', 'r') as f:
        inflation = []
        header = 1
        for line in f:
            if header == 1:
                header += 1
                continue
            else:
                infl = line.split(",")[2]
                inflation.append(float(infl))

        avgInflation = sum(inflation)/len(inflation)

    return avgInflation
```

I think this should solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

As I see you initiate variable `header` as 1 outside the for loop. 
Inside the for loop you check if the `header` is not equal to 1 and not do anything if it equals to 1.
For loop never goes inside the `if header !=1:` 
It just iterates over your whole file and goes out of for loop without doing anything.
In line 11, `len(inflation)` is 0 since you never append anything to it. 
You should change your conditional loop or change your variable `header` in somewhere in your code.

```
def myTest(file):
 with open ('filename', 'r') as f:
      inflation = []
      header = 1
      for line in f:
           if header !=1: //Never goes inside
                infl = line.split(",")[2]
                inflation.append(float(infl))
                header += 1

       avgInflation = sum(inflation)/len(inflation) //Divison by zero

 return avgInflation
```